# Zoho integration with test stripe account failed

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

Hii i have made a test organization in zoho and i want to connect the payent ateway with stripe when i am providing it the test card information it is not accepting it and giving me this error

"Known test bank accounts cannot be used in live mode."
[This is the screen shot of test account of US i am adding in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8IOi.png)

also when i go to its market place and try to activate stripe payment gatewat it gives me issue that you need to firt checkout

I want to connect my stripe test account with this zoho account